# Apache Config variables

Tags: apache-http-server

I have some difficulties to understand the apache variables described in here:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars

What I need to use in my directive:

1. The IP of the webserver the apache is running on
2. The IP of the client trying to access the server
3. The URL (string) the client is trying to access
4. Alternatively, a boolean telling me whether the current request is coming from the server itself

---

As far as I understand, REMOTE_ADDR must be the client's IP. But where is the Servers ID hidden? SERVER_ADDR does not exist...

Comment: Not an answer, but you should [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you are attempting to accomplish. What directive? What is your general setup? What are you (I assume) trying to protect? Please do not answer in the comments.

Comment: <If "%{CLIENT_IP} != %{SERVER_IP}">
  Require all denied 
</If>

Comment: Why wouldn't you know the server IP? And why not use e.g. `Require ip 1.2.3.4` where `1.2.3.4` is the server address. And what is the server address anyway? A loop back address e.g. `127.0.0.1`, the local IP address, or some other public address?

Comment: I simply need to check whether the request came from the same machine apache is running on.